# Use XSD file in XBAP application

Tags: wpf, xml, xsd, .net-assembly, xbap

In an existing Winforms application, I receive XML formatted data from a database query, and use a local XSD file to parse the resulting XML element.

Now, I'd like to achieve the same from within a WPF XBAP (application in browser), so no local XSD file is accessible.

Obviously I can load the XSD file onto my web server, but how do I tell WPF to use this schema file for parsing the XML chunk?

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlnsDefinition and XmlnsPrefix assemblies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/11/02/wpf-tired-of-xmlns-clr-namespace.aspx) to map the XSD file to page element or XML root element.